# Fallout 4 Pink Fog Effect on all NPCs

Tags: fallout-4

[image: The pink Effect]

This is a picture of what is happening. I've tried swapping all of my clothes and weapons in case some of them had an odd effect. I haven't installed any mod that should do this (I have a generator quieting one, a body hair one, the full sentence dialogue, some texture replacements, and pip boy shadows).

Sometimes it vanishes while in dialogue but most of the time it's just like this on everyone it's driving me mad and ruining my screenshots. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Try disabling your mods. They **shouldnt** do it, if they work completely as intended. But this is not often the case with mods. I could speculate that the body hair mod might be the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you taking Berry Mentats? That is the secondary effect of the Berry Mentats it highlights the enemy allowing you to see them better even through walls. Here is a link there is a picture at the bottom that shows the effect when looking through a wall same effect.http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Berry_Mentats_%28Fallout_4%29

Comment: That is the exact effect, I can see people through walls and such. But the thing is I've never taken Berry Mentats? I've taken Jet and Psycho but this Mentats effect will stay for the entire time of a 5 hour play session.

I will try taking some to see if when they wear off they take the rest of this off with it. Thank you so much.

Comment: There is a power armor helmet modification that does the same thing. I can't remember the name off the top of my head.

Comment: There is a power armor mod, but the effect is more like a red stripe overlay, not the berry mentats glow.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem the other day and I couldn't figure out what was going on.

As Nightmare mentioned, this is the effect of the Berry Mentats. Even after learning this I was still a bit confused and thought it must be a bug as I haven't been using them, yet the effect kept starting whenever I got into a fight and it would last for a while.

Turns out that I gave some to Piper earlier with some other items I was trading with her and she was using them automatically when we got into combat. I took them away from her and sure enough it stopped. So, you may want to check your companion's inventory if it keeps happening. I didn't realize that companions would use them, less that the effect that the berry mentats would also affect me, but apparently they do.

Comment: The power armor effect is shared via your follower in the same way. So if you have your follower in power armor with the helmet mod that tracks entities the same thing will happen.